# Change RootViewController & Remove All View Controllers

Tags: swift

I am having difficulty replacing the rootViewController in a custom class that constantly observers if a user is logged in or not.

While it does change the root view controller, the previous view controller & any presented views are still there underneath. How can I completely clear the slate and reset to a new view controller?

```
 func isLoggedIn () {

        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main Menu")

    }
```

Comment: "What is the best way to essentially completely clear the slate and reset to a new view controller?"  What makes one way the best of all?

Comment: Let's go with, what would you do in this situation?

Comment: You can also add a new window and make that the key window. Or you can dynamically change the content views of a TabBar ViewController. However, I fear, when looking at the code provided, that your intention should be solved in a completely different approach.

Comment: @ElTomato The "best" bit is easily ignored without changing the crux of the question. I've edited it now to clarify it and remove any opinion-based concerns.

Comment: CouchDeveloper; I am not using a tab bar controller. This is simply showing a Log In View first then showing the main menu. What would be a completely different approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UINavigationController {
/**
 It removes all view controllers from navigation controller then set the new root view controller and it pops.
 
 - parameter vc: root view controller to set a new
 */
func initRootViewController(vc: UIViewController, transitionType type: String = kCATransition, duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.3) {
    self.addTransition(transitionType: type, duration: duration)
    self.viewControllers.removeAll()
    self.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
    self.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
}

/**
 It adds the animation of navigation flow.
 
 - parameter type: kCATransitionType, it means style of animation
 - parameter duration: CFTimeInterval, duration of animation
 */
private func addTransition(transitionType type: String = kCATransition, duration: CFTimeInterval = 0.3) {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = duration
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    transition.type = CATransitionType(rawValue: type)
    self.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
}}
```

Use this

Comment: My app is not using a navigation controller... ?

Comment: Then you must be saving logged in state in Userdefaults. if not save it and check it while assigning the rootViewController

Comment: Sorry, that does not address the problem related to UIWindow. This has nothing to do with the saving of log in state in user defaults.